# How can I ship Gstreamer with my Go project?

Tags: windows, go, dll, gstreamer

I have a Golang project that uses gstreamer (with dxgiscreencapsrc plugin) to capture the user screen. Right now gstreamer is installed on my windows system in MSYS2.

Is there a way to ship the dll files of gstreamer with my go app, so the user doesn't have to install it?

The only possible solution I found is this: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/deploying/windows.html?gi-language=c , but not sure if it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your link looks like what you need.